# PHP wildcard page handler

Tags: php, url

In JSP using tomcat I can specify a directory to go to a servlet handler and use the filename as a parameter.
IS there any way I can do this in PHP.

The purpose of this in this instance is I have a shop, so all products are of the form

```
shop_view.php?cat=3 
shop_detail.php?id=432
```

and although those work, and I am not trying to remove those entirely, it would be nice when providing links to a product to people to give links such as

```
products/bottle_brush
categories/accessories
```

which I could easily lookup from the database. If only I could catch the directories products/* and categories/*

Comment: What server software are you on? Apache?

Comment: This sounds like a job for Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: this is on apache yes, I will have to check what is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to store the product and category slugs along with the product in the database and make sure they are unique (if required).

Then you need to implement the requests shop_detail.php?slug=bottle_brush and shop_view.php?cat=accessories

Finally, if you are using Apache and the mod-rewrite module is activated, you can use the .htaccess file to rewrite your URLs (did not test that, refer to mod_rewrite documentation and .htaccess tutorials):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^products\/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ shop_detail.php?slug=$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks for that info. I will check to see if I can use mod_rewrite. I never realised that is what it could do!

Answer (score 1):

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Shortest answer ever. It would certainly be more detailed to be accepted IMHO. Anyway, you could develop an example with `.htaccess` (as we don't know if he got access to _httpd.conf_)

Comment: he doesn't need to type anything longer - click on mod_rewrite and it takes you to the manual ..

Comment: thanks for the info, I gave the answer for the 'how to use' section below, as it covered it a bit better, but appreciate it anyway